# High pitched beep for 3 seconds every 15 minutes

Tags: electrical

Can anyone help? I keep hearing a 3 second high pitched beep but can't quite tell where it is coming from. It’s loudest in my dining room. We are moving so I have packed stuff up but it almost sounds like it could be coming from my attic. I’m going crazy. I have turned every breaker off in my house to check appliances, I have taken batteries out of all of the detectors in my house even my ADT security system. I’m going crazy. It’s 3 second every 17 minutes and it goes off starting at 1356 and last one is at 2209.

Comment: https://www.thegreenhead.com/2008/12/annoy-a-tron-2.php

Comment: This sounds like a device on a timer intending to perform an action but some operating condition is not met. For instance: a water filter system that needs to operate but has no water supply/pressure because a valve to it is shut-off or a pump feeding it is not activating. What's in the attic? Is there a detector in there? The furnace/AC? Water purification system? The source of a high-pitched tone is sometimes difficult to pin-point, since they seem to come from different directions even if you just turn your head (long story of physics, size of your ear shell etc...). So it might not be in t

Comment: Can you explain further what you say about the dining room and attic?  If you go in the attic is it louder or softer than in the dining room?    When I'm in your situation I sit with a book to read half way up a stairway with my body facing sideways to the stairs.  I find that very effective at identifying which floor the noise is coming from.  Once I know the floor it's usually not that hard.  The only things I can think of that would make such noises with all power removed are smoke/CO detectors and alarm system components .... but the alarm system would hopefully trigger notifications.

Comment: Could the noise be coming from a neighbor?  Is there a restaurant or other business near you that keeps those hours and might have some device calling for attention?  Previous cases of odd noises inside, have been tied to insects, trains, loading bays, and other nearby outside sources.

Comment: I once had this on a long-haul bus trip, with my travel alarm clock packed in a bag, and suddenly it went off in the underbelly of the bus. Took us all a while to figure out what it was. And of course... my embarrassment when we figured it out.

Comment: CO detectors plug in and have batteries, they will do that. You can load a DB app to your phone and probe around with that until you find the source.

Comment: My answer, with an upvote (!), was converted by @BMitch to a comment. It's at the top now, but with missing pieces. Not sure how that better helps the OP or anyone else.

Comment: AirWick scent diffuser with dying batteries. Took us a couple weeks to find in a cabinet (not being used).

Comment: You sure someone isn't pranking you with a beeper? https://www.amazon.com/AnnoyingPCB-Ultimate-Productivity-Destroyer-Assembled/dp/B08KG6XHN1

Comment: There are gag beepers people can buy cheap and hide somewhere for the explicit reason of driving a homeowner nuts over the coming weeks and months.  You have any screwball friends over lately????

Comment: I would suspect a smoke detector.

Comment: I've flagged as a duplicate because while the specific sound is a little different, the solution is the same

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this problem you probably own an AIR-WICK ...the battery operated one that spits out a scent every so often. Well this thing is programed to do a check every 10 mins between 2:00pm and 10:00pm...and there made of cheap electronics. turn it off and then to max and u will replicate the high pitch noise